# Accessing PC on Switch if Router is turned-off?

Tags: switch, router

I have the following:

**Router**

Has PC A

**Switch Hub**

Has PC B
Has PC C

Assuming everything works. Just wanted to know if I turn-off the router, can PC B and C still communicate?

And if I turn router back on, can they still see again PC A? Even let's say the IP changes?

Thanks

Comment: You should describe the network better (a diagram would be great), and include the device models and configurations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, PC's B and C will be able to communicate with each other, via the switch, as long as they are on the same subnet and vlan and the switch is a dumb switch.

If it's a managed switch, you could of configured something so they that can't but you'd know if you'd done this.

Answer (score 2):

Of course B and C can exchange packets so long as they are statically configured and addressing each other by IP address; but you might find there are hidden dependencies on the router or A that can get in the way.

A typical surprise might be DHCP services on the router being unavailable so B and C fail to get IP addresses or their leases expire causing failure many hours after router goes down.  Another can be cause by inaccessible DNS services on A preventing them finding each other or reversing the other's IP address for logging purposes.

They can "still communicate"; whether they will depends on what kind of communications you want them to use and the details of their network.

Kind regards,

Jonathan.